# Sql 2000 attach Error 5172

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

When I attach a database file from SQL Server 2000 Standard Edition to SQL Server 2000 Database  on another  machine ,
I am receive the following error.

```
"Error 5172: The heather for file 'D:...' is not a valid database file header.
 The PageAudit property is incorrect."
```

I can not transfer data.What should I do?

Comment: Your DB files may have become corrupt. Do you have a backup of the DB?

Comment: @Stan the DBA - I don't have any backup of my database.

Comment: Are you still able to attach it on the original server and create a backup file?

Comment: Did you check the SQL Server levels of the source and destination? If the original source database server is a higher patch level than the destination, it might cause problems like this....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file's corrupt.  You either need a backup, or you need to engage with a consultant who can try manually editing the file.  (I'm not one of those consultants, and they're not cheap - you're in five-figure territory.)